# Do not have to print "x" in first line.what to do?

Tags: python

```
a = ""
b = ""
c = 1
for j in range(5,0,-1):
    a = "*" + a
    b = b + "x"
    print(c*' ' + j*'-' + a + b)
```

I am getting the following output:

```
 -----*x
 ----**xx
 ---***xxx
 --****xxxx
 -*****xxxxx
```

But I want to get the following output:

```
 -----*
 ----**x
 ---***xx
 --****xxx
 -*****xxxx
```

It's printing `x` in the first line.
I don’t have to print `x` in first line.
The pyramid of `x` will start from the 2nd line.

Comment: You should add the result you want.

Comment: Please add your current and expected result. It will be much clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trivial solution would be to add an if condition as below:

```
    a=""
    b=""
    c=1
    for j in range(5,0,-1):
        a ="*"+a
        if j < 5:
            b = b + "x"
        print(c*' '+j*'-'+a+b)
```

if you want output in one line

Comment: Tnx arajshree .